# Issue removing VM from VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I want to remove Virtual Machine and I have deleted VM folder from hd.
It's still shown in the VirtualBox GUI but the settings are grayed out.

Comment: Just go to where you saved your VM HDD, all the files related to your VM will be there, just delete the directory and it'll be gone

Answer (score 2):

The properties are disabled because the VM is missing.
Now through the GUI you can:
Right-click -> Delete